# Run executable on MINI2440 with NO OS

Tags: arm, embedded, embedded-linux

I have Fedora installed on my PC and I have a [Friendly ARM Mini2440](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/mini2440) board. I have successfully installed Linux kernel and everything is working. Now I have some image processing program, which I want to run on the board without OS. The only process running on board should be my program. And in that program how can I access the on board camera to take image from, and serial port to send output to the PC.

Comment: The terminology for a program without an OS is a standalone or bare-metal program.  The obvious question is "why?"

Comment: Why is not any of our concern...not related to the question...

Comment: serial to the pc is the first, thing, you need to figure that out if you didnt already getting linux running.  see the manuals from the vendor.  they are most likely using a bootloader like uboot.  interrupt the boot with a keystroke and there is likely a loadx or loady command from which you can download a bare metal program, get the docs for the processor, using the bootloader commands write to the uart tx register and see if a character comes out then go from there, google bare metal arm or something.  camera is a much larger problem to solve, but likely doable if you have documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about what is often called a *[bare-metal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bare_machine)* environment. Google can help you, for example [here](http://www.embedded.com/design/mcus-processors-and-socs/4007119/Building-Bare-Metal-ARM-Systems-with-GNU-Part-1--Getting-Started). In a bare-metal environment you have to have a good understanding of your hardware because you have to take care of a lot of things that the OS normally handles.

I've been working (off and on) on bare-metal support for my [ELLCC](http://ellcc.org) cross development tool-chain. I have the ARM implementation pretty far along but there is still quite a bit of work to do. I have written about some of my experiences on my [blog](http://ellcc.org/blog/?tag=bare-metal).

First off, you have to get your program started. You'll need to write some start-up code, usually in assembly, to handle the initialization of the processor as it comes out of reset (or is powered on). The start-up code then typically passes control to code written in C that ultimately directly or indirectly calls your main() function. Getting to main() is a huge step in your bare-metal adventure!

Next, you need to decide how to support your hardware's I/O devices which in your case include the camera and serial port. How much of the standard C (or C++) library does your image processing require? You might need to add some support for functions like printf() or malloc() that normally need some kind of OS support. A simple "hello world" would be a good thing to try next.

ELLCC has examples of various levels of ARM bare-metal in the [examples](http://ellcc.org/viewvc/svn/ellcc/trunk/examples/) directory. They range from a simple main() up to and including MMU and TCP/IP support. The source for all of it can be browsed [here](http://ellcc.org/viewvc/svn/ellcc/trunk/libecc/src/elk/).

I started writing this before I left for work this morning and didn't have time to finish. Both dwelch and Clifford had good suggestions. A bootloader might make your job a lot simpler and documentation on your hardware is crucial.

Comment: Sir, You are right , It definitely needs a lot of time to digest it all. So for now i have selected a very light weight OS ,[http://code.google.com/p/startos/]'StartOS' to get started with. This OS only runs executable in SDCard and provides driver support for all the peripherals. Thank You So much . You are a great help.

Answer (score 0):

First you must realise that without an OS, you are responsible for bringing the board up from reset including configuring the PLL and SDRAM, and also for the driver code for every device on the board you wish to use.  To do that required adequate documentation of the board and it devices.

It is possible that you can use the existing bootloader to configure the core and SDRAM, but that may not meet your requirement for the only process running on the board should be your image processing program.

Additionally you will need some means of loading and bootstrapping; again the existing Linux bootstrapper may suit.

It is by no means straightforward and cannot really be described in detail here.

Comment: Sir, You are right, Now i am working on (http://code.google.com/p/startos/) 'StartOS'. Thank you for your support and guidance . :)